# Is there a way to change Windows XP "open file" dialog with something better?

Tags: windows-xp, everything

I mean this dialog that pops up when you try to open a file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpt2y.png

Is there a way to change this; perhaps into something similar to [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)?

Edit: also, are Windows 7 / Mac OS / Linux equivalents better?

Answer (score 2):

Dialog windows are Microsoft Components (Open/Save windows etc), and you can not change them visually. **EDIT:** *Extremely limited in what you can add or remove, or change ...* besides what MS gives you. THey all look the same, like crwap. A developer would have to create their own form that mimics a dialog, and that would only work within their application.

You could use an explorer replacement... but that wouldn't change the dialog windows, just the explorer window. Unless you meant explorer windows... like  Xplorer2 as replacement. There are quite a few more like it.

Comment: This just isn't true.  The common file dialog API provides a mechanism for the application to extend the dialog (although it's incompatible with the "new" look).  I'm not aware of any way to globally customize the dialog though, it has to be requested by code running in-process.

Comment: Extremely limited in what you can do or extend, I should say.

Comment: `OFN_ENABLEHOOK` limited?  Not really.  Just [a compatibility nightmare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731218/ofn-enablehook-modifies-the-look-of-getopenfilename)